# CSV fields max length error and setting quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE

Tags: quoting, csv, csvkit

After running `csvcut` on a comma-delimited .csv file:

```
[root@server files]# csvcut -c title,mpn,overview,techspecs2,image_carousel_elargesrc syn_multi-image.csv > syn_scraped_cut.csv
```

I get the error:

> CSV contains fields longer than maximum length of 131072 characters.
> Try raising the maximum with the field_size_limit parameter, or try
> setting quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE.

Though large, I can tell you for sure that my longest field is only 65535 characters long, which is under the maximum allowed length by a pretty safe margin.

I have no idea what setting `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` refers to.  I have only been using simple csvkit commands and that is all I know.

Reading similar threads and answers such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063936/csv-error-field-larger-than-field-limit-131072) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18408911/9095603), I am unable to extract any kind of solution in the context of csvkit, specifically.  I'm not adept at programming in general and am limited to using csvkit, its commands and options.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Probably there is some error in the CSV. Could you share a portion of it and before sharing it check that you have the same error applying csvcut on it?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_arguments.html) of the `csvkit` states that the `-z` argument can be used to adjust the `FIELD_SIZE_LIMIT`.

So I suggest trying with a fairly high number:

```
csvcut -z 2500000 -c title,mpn,overview,techspecs2,image_carousel_elargesrc syn_multi-image.csv > syn_scraped_cut.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error when converting a CSV file to a sqlite database. the table contained more than a million records. also the table did not contain fields in which there were 65535 records. The solution was to write a script that divided a large table into small tables containing 100,000 records each and loaded them into a sqlite database. no more errors occurred.